# do you know another Magic Square with this property?

Tags: prime-numbers, decimal-expansion, magic-square

with the repeating digits of $\frac{1}{19} = 0.052631578947368421$ we can construct an exceptional magic square :

> The number 19 is a cyclic number with a period of 18 before the digits
> start to repeat.
>
> The full term decimal expansion of the prime number 19 when multiplied
> by the values 1 to 18, may be arranged in a simple magic square of
> order-18, if the decimal point is ignored. All 18 rows, columns and
> the two main diagonals sum to the same value. S = 81. Of course this
> is not a pure magic square because a consecutive series of numbers
> from 1 to n is not used

[example of order 18](http://www.magic-squares.net/magic_squares_index.htm)
(Moved to an answer. The link died.)

Are there **other numbers as well *19 and 383*** that can be used for making magic squares in such way ?

**is it proved that in base 10 only *19 and 383* have this property ? , what is for higher orders ?**

Comment: Your link (or a [slightly more helpful version](http://www.magic-squares.net/magic_squares_index.htm#Order-18%20based%20on%201/19)) says the next base-$10$ value that works is $383$

Comment: What you're saying is that (1) the periods of the decimal expansions of the numbers $n/19$, $1\leq n\leq18$ are all of length $18$, (2) if we therefore place these expansions each on their own row, we get a square of side length $18$, and (3) this is a magic square. Is that right?

Comment: you are right @JackM !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numbers that work are tabulated at the [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/A072359), where some references to the literature are given.

Comment: thanks @Grry Myerson this is the definitive answer .

Answer (score 1):

The link died, so here is the array for $19$. The numbers would be put into ascending order of the fraction ($1/19, 2/19, ...$).

$\begin{array}&
0&5&2&6&3&1&5&7&8&9&4&7&3&6&8&4&2&1\\
1&0&5&2&6&3&1&5&7&8&9&4&7&3&6&8&4&2\\
1&5&7&8&9&4&7&3&6&8&4&2&1&0&5&2&6&3\\
2&1&0&5&2&6&3&1&5&7&8&9&4&7&3&6&8&4\\
2&6&3&1&5&7&8&9&4&7&3&6&8&4&2&1&0&5\\
3&1&5&7&8&9&4&7&3&6&8&4&2&1&0&5&2&6\\
3&6&8&4&2&1&0&5&2&6&3&1&5&7&8&9&4&7\\
4&2&1&0&5&2&6&3&1&5&7&8&9&4&7&3&6&8\\
4&7&3&6&8&4&2&1&0&5&2&6&3&1&5&7&8&9\\
5&2&6&3&1&5&7&8&9&4&7&3&6&8&4&2&1&0\\
5&7&8&9&4&7&3&6&8&4&2&1&0&5&2&6&3&1\\
6&3&1&5&7&8&9&4&7&3&6&8&4&2&1&0&5&2\\
6&8&4&2&1&0&5&2&6&3&1&5&7&8&9&4&7&3\\
7&3&6&8&4&2&1&0&5&2&6&3&1&5&7&8&9&4\\
7&8&9&4&7&3&6&8&4&2&1&0&5&2&6&3&1&5\\
8&4&2&1&0&5&2&6&3&1&5&7&8&9&4&7&3&6\\
8&9&4&7&3&6&8&4&2&1&0&5&2&6&3&1&5&7\\
9&4&7&3&6&8&4&2&1&0&5&2&6&3&1&5&7&8\\
\end{array}$